# query takes too much time while sorting in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance

Query :
select field1 as Word,count(*) as Count from TestAdd1214190 group by field1 order by count desc

Btree Index created on field1 column

Data In table 50 lac

Engine : MEMORY

Explain
TYPE: SIMPLE

USING INDEX;USING TEMPORORY;USING FILESORT

Please suggest how do i make this query fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Count(*)` is optimized by MySql there could be performance differences on which column you use. You can try to us `Count([index field name])` instead.

Refer to: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/ for more info on this matter.

Comment: thank you for responce. Varchar type of clolumns i am using like Address,PAN_NUMBER etc.